# Looks like the useHistory.goBack() from react-router is triggered twice

Tags: reactjs

I am using `const history = useHistory()` from `react-router`, and I do a `history.push(/my-url)`, which works fine, and when the user wants to go back, I use the `history.goBack()`. This does not work correctly now. It makes the user go back two pages instead of one. What can the cause be?

Answer (score 1):

I found my bug:
I was firing an `history.goBack()` when the dialog is closing in addition to when I close the dialog with one of the "close buttons".